# Yet another PHP dateTime format issue no2

Tags: php

I have been going through all the related links to this issue but nothing seems to be working for me ... unless I pass a static dateTime to the conversion the code below doesn't return anything. I am getting a dateTime string from an SQL Db, with the following format `Y-m-d H:i:s`. Example: `2017-07-03 09:00:00`

Here is code that works fine and sticks the same dateTime in every corresponding table cell.

```
 <?php
 if ($sOtaskCount > 0) {
 echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Date Due</th><th>Description</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $sOtasks, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s','2017-07-03 09:00:00']);
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["ID"]. "</td><td>" . date_format($date,'Y-m-d H:i:s'). "</td><td> " . $row["Description"]. "</td></tr>";
      }
   } 
   else {
       echo "No Other Tasks to Display!";
        }
  ?>
```

Here is the same code, but pulling in dateTime from $row, that isn't returning anything. All the other entries from the Db (ID and Description) are returned correctly.

```
 <?php
 if ($sOtaskCount > 0) {
 echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Date Due</th><th>Description</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $sOtasks, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s',$row["Date_Due"]);
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["ID"]. "</td><td>" . date_format($date,'Y-m-d H:i:s'). "</td><td> " . $row["Description"]. "</td></tr>";
      }
   } 
   else {
       echo "No Other Tasks to Display!";
        }
  ?>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just curious: your `$row["Date_Due"]` is in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format, so why are you parsing it into a `DateTime` object only to format that into `Y-m-d H:i:s` format later? Can't you just output `$row["Date_Due"]` directly instead of passing it through a `DateTime` object?

Comment: Also, `print_r($row);`

Comment: And if your $row['Date_Due'] is populated, then - as you can see - I will try to use simple quotes to get datas from $row. It could be the source of the problem too. 
Maybe use DateTime::createFromFormat( string $format , string $time [, DateTimeZone $timezone ] ). With the DateTimeZone it could work better I think.
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: It would appear the dateTime has some trailing zeros. Below is the `print_r($row)`

`Array ( [ID] => 39 [Due_Date] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2016-07-03 13:12:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Minsk ) [Description] => Estimate 100001 due to expire. `

Comment: I am still unsure on how to handle this however....

Answer (score 0):

Since the dateTime value from `$row` is not returning anything and a static value works, it seems the problem is from the `$row` object itself. You can do a `print_r($row)` to see if it contains the expected data, and the right key(s) to use for the datetime object (as suggested by AbraCadaver).

Also, as pointed out by rickdenhaan, why not just leave `$row["Date_Due"]` as-is, since it's already in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format from the db?

--- **Edit Based on result of `print_r($row)`** ---

From the output of `print_r($row)`, you should access the dateTime with

`$row['Due_Date']->date`

as `$row['Due_Date']` itself is an object, not a string, and that's why you are getting the "Unix start time" when you use it directly.

Comment: Hi.
Having `$row["Due_Date"]` in the table doesnt return anything. I have responded to AbraCadaver above as I can now see what the problem is.

Comment: I have tried the following, but no joy.

`$date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u',$row["Due_Date"]);`
    
`echo "<tr><td>" . $row["ID"]. "</td><td>" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date). "</td><td> " . $row["Description"]. "</td></tr>";`

Comment: This creates the following dateTime in the table, which is an improvement I guess ;)

**1970-01-01 03:00:00**

Comment: I have also tired the following but its returning 1970-01-01 (which I know is Unix start time)

                                                `$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row["due_date"]));
                                                echo "<tr><td>" . $row["ID"]. "</td><td>" . $date . "</td><td> " . $row["Description"]. "</td></tr>";`

Comment: Please see edited answer. `$row["Due_Date"]` is an object, not a string.

Comment: Might have to hold my hand through this one.

I have the following, but again, date is **1970-01-01**

                                                `$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row["Due_Date"]->date));
                                                echo "<tr><td>" . $row["ID"]. "</td><td>" . $date . "</td><td> " . $row["Description"]. "</td></tr>";`

Comment: Huh? Shouldn't be. This indicates that what you are passing to `strtotime` isn't a valid time string yet, or is an empty string. Can check your spelling, do `print_r($row['Due_Date']->date)` (expected to return `2016-07-03 13:12:00.000000`, which is the time string we need here) or perhaps try `print_r($row['Due_Date']['date'])`?

Comment: I am using VS Code, so I dont have an IDE to step through the script or anything, when I reload the page with the `print_r($row['Due_Date']['date'])` the div that contains the info doesn't appear (it appears on mouse hover)

I created a new DateTime object and it shows as the following:
`object(DateTime)#2 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2017-07-10 12:27:35.809780" 

Whereas `$row[''Due_Date'] shows as:
`Array ( [ID] => 39 [Due_Date] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2016-07-03 13:12:00.000000 `

There are subtle differences, which, as you say, may mean $row isnt in the right format??

Comment: The only way I have been able to do this is to cast the Due_Date as a VARCHAR in the SQL query, then output it as its text format in PHP. Not a biggie as I am doing very small queries, returning < 100 rows. 

`SELECT ID,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Due_Date, 105) AS [Due_Date], Description, Completed, Type
                            FROM Tasks   
                                where type = '4'  AND completed = '0'`

Comment: Something seems wrong with the `$row` data and it needs to be carefully inspected. If only you could share a fiddle (or something similar) that gives a feel of the real environment...